# dataset transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm getting error

****Dataset transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x, see SPARK-28702****

Here is my code

```
do {
        val size = accumulatorList.value.size()
        val current = accumulatorList.value.get(size -1)
        joinoutput = current.join(broadvast.value, current.col("A") === broadvast.value.col("A"))
        .map {x =>
                
                    
        val gig = x._1.getAs("Name") + "|" + x._1.getAs("PIP")
            
        MyData(
        x._2.getAs("Name"),
        x._2.getAs("Place"),
        x._2.getAs("Phone"),
        x._2.getAs("Doc"),
        gig 
        )}          
        accumulatorList.add(joinoutput)
        joincount = joinoutput.count()

}

while (joincount >0 )
```

This error is coming while I'm joining in do block. Its running fine in my local/cluster but failing while I'm building my code with test cases. Even my test case is running fine in local, but the problem is only coming while building it.

Can anyone suggest please what's wrong happening and what can be done to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the rest of 'creating instances for DataFrame' code? Probably there are workarounds for your case, because there is no general workaround for this problem, other than using `.collect()` first, then using map, but then you might have bad performance as the computations happen in the driver and not executors.

Comment: @vilalabinot, added please check now, can I use cache() ? If not then how to convert Array[Row] to DataFrame, because collect returns Array[Row] ?